# HTML CSS Posicionamiento de elementos

Tags: html, css, web, diseño

Necesito posicionar tres cajas de esta forma:

[image: Como debe quedar]

A Eventos y Glosario colocarlo al lado de Productos, y del titulo los mejores.

Copio mi codigo de como fui en HTML modelando los divs.

```
<div class="contenedor1">
<h1> <img src="imagenes/productos.gif">Productos </h1>

<div class="contenido">
<p> Las mejores variedades</p>
<img src="imagenes/images5.jpg">
</div>

<div class="contenido">
<p>Carta de vinos</p>
<img src="imagenes/cartavino.jpg">
</div>

<div class="contenido">
<p>Las mejores bodegas </p>
<img src="imagenes/images9.jpg">
</div>

</div>



<div class="contenedor2">
<div class="cont2">
<h1><img src="imagenes/iconoevento.gif"> Eventos </h1>
<h5> Mayo 2011</h5>
<p> Se celebra en la provincia de <br>
Mendoza, el primer fin de <br>
semana de marzo (casi sin <br>
interrupciones desde 1936) y <br>
se trata del homenaje que el <br>
hombre le dedica a su <br>
industria principal: la <br>
vivinicola. </p>
</div>


<div class="cont2">
<h1> <img src="imagenes/glosario.gif">Glosario </h1>
<p> Enólogo: <br>
Experto responsable de <br>
dirigir y asesorar en el <br>
proceso de elaboración <br>
del vino y su almacenaje, <br>
análisi, conservación, <br>
embotellados y <br>
comercialización. <br>
Estudia asimismo el <br>
proceso del cultivo de la <br>
vid, así como los suelos <br>
aptos para determinados <br>
cepajes y otros temas <br>
vinculados.
</p>
</div>


<div class="contenedor3">
<div class="cont3">
<h1>Los Mejores </h1>
<h2>La región vitinícola en Argentina se desarrolla <br> entre los 22° y 42° de latitud sur </h2>
<p> <b> Santa Florentia </b> propome el espumante ideal para acompañar el <br>
brindis de estas fiestas: <b> el BRUT de torrontés </b>, nacido en las<br>
tierras riojanas de los Valles del Famatima. Este espumante es un <br>
<b> varietal 100% torrontés riojano</b>, de sabor fresco y óptima <br>
acidez que se exalta con el frizante de las burbujas, y permite que <br>
los aromas frutales se realcen en boca. <b> BRUT de torrontes </b> <br>
presenta un intenso sabor, con notas de azahares, frutas citricas y <br>
ananá, que exalta los sentidos por su frescura y equilibrada <br>
acidez.</p> 
<br>
<p>Comprar vino significa saber elegir el vino de <br> 
acuerdo a los gustos de cada consumidor.<br></p>

<p> Según el Observatorio Vitinicola Argentino, por el Malbec se <br>
pagó un precio promedio ponderado de $422 el quintal; por el <br>
Chardonnay, $233 el quintal y por la variedad Aspirant Bouchet <br>
$570. Claras diferencias de precio por zona.<br>

</div>
```

y es css:

```
.contenedor1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: baseline;
  width:55%;
}

.contenido {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
}



.contenedor2 {

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}

.cont2 {
  padding: 0px 10px 10px 40px; 
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  background-color:#3B0B0B;
  width: 19%;
  color:#ffffff;
}


.contenedor3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.cont3 {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo el uso de la libreria de js, html y css Bootstrap. Tiene un sistema de grid que te solucionaría el problema en un momento. Aquí esta la documentación https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: No hay otra forma con solamente css3 y html5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existen muchas formas de organizar por columnas, puedes usar propiedades `display: inline-block` como también puedes usar el `display: flex` en un elemento padre que contenga los 3 elementos, en este ejemplo he solucionado el problema con otra forma diferente a las dos que te he dicho anteriormente, basta con usar `float:left` en las columnas y aplicarle a cada una un `width` para que se organicen como lo requieres:

**NOTA:** al sumar los `width` de las 3 columnas debe dar como total 100% ya que se considera que el ancho total de la pantalla equivale al 100%. Si al sumar los `width` de las columnas se sobrepasara ese valor la última columna rompería la alineación horizontal y se bajaría. También debes tomar en cuenta las márgenes externas e internas de los elementos (`margin` y `padding`) ya que éstas afectas el `width`.

Puedes probar el ejecutar en pantalla completa, ya si lo quieres responsive debes usar los `media queries`

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.contenedor1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: baseline;
    width:55%;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}

.contenido {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 5px;
}

.contenedor2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

.cont2 {
    padding: 0px 10px 10px 40px; 
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    background-color:#3B0B0B;
    width: 100%;
    color:#ffffff;
}

.contenedor3 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: baseline;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.cont3 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor1">
    <h1> <img src="imagenes/productos.gif">Productos </h1>

    <div class="contenido">
        <p> Las mejores variedades</p>
        <img src="imagenes/images5.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="contenido">
        <p>Carta de vinos</p>
        <img src="imagenes/cartavino.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="contenido">
        <p>Las mejores bodegas </p>
        <img src="imagenes/images9.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="contenedor2">
    <div class="cont2">
        <h1><img src="imagenes/iconoevento.gif"> Eventos </h1>
        <h5> Mayo 2011</h5>
        <p> 
            Se celebra en la provincia de <br>
            Mendoza, el primer fin de <br>
            semana de marzo (casi sin <br>
            interrupciones desde 1936) y <br>
            se trata del homenaje que el <br>
            hombre le dedica a su <br>
            industria principal: la <br>
            vivinicola.
        </p>
    </div>


    <div class="cont2">
        <h1> <img src="imagenes/glosario.gif">Glosario </h1>
        <p> 
            Enólogo: <br>
            Experto responsable de <br>
            dirigir y asesorar en el <br>
            proceso de elaboración <br>
            del vino y su almacenaje, <br>
            análisi, conservación, <br>
            embotellados y <br>
            comercialización. <br>
            Estudia asimismo el <br>
            proceso del cultivo de la <br>
            vid, así como los suelos <br>
            aptos para determinados <br>
            cepajes y otros temas <br>
            vinculados.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="contenedor3">
    <div class="cont3">
        <h1>Los Mejores </h1>
        <h2>La región vitinícola en Argentina se desarrolla <br> entre los 22° y 42° de latitud sur </h2>
        <p> 
            <b>Santa Florentia</b> propome el espumante ideal para acompañar el <br>
            brindis de estas fiestas: <b> el BRUT de torrontés </b>, nacido en las<br>
            tierras riojanas de los Valles del Famatima. Este espumante es un <br>
            <b> varietal 100% torrontés riojano</b>, de sabor fresco y óptima <br>
            acidez que se exalta con el frizante de las burbujas, y permite que <br>
            los aromas frutales se realcen en boca. <b> BRUT de torrontes </b> <br>
            presenta un intenso sabor, con notas de azahares, frutas citricas y <br>
            ananá, que exalta los sentidos por su frescura y equilibrada <br>
            acidez.
        </p> 
        <br>
        <p>
            Comprar vino significa saber elegir el vino de <br> 
            acuerdo a los gustos de cada consumidor.<br>
        </p>

        <p>
            Según el Observatorio Vitinicola Argentino, por el Malbec se <br>
            pagó un precio promedio ponderado de $422 el quintal; por el <br>
            Chardonnay, $233 el quintal y por la variedad Aspirant Bouchet <br>
            $570. Claras diferencias de precio por zona.<br>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```